# Safest place to sit in the car

Tags: forces, collision

I have to sit in a car which has normal seats in the front, and lounge type chairs at the back, with seatbelts only in the front. The driver drives fast, and I think I may have an accident. So, according to physics, where should I sit to be safest? Front, with belts, or back??

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=omni+van+interior+seats&hl=en-US&espv=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sboxchip=Images&sa=X&ei=7iqvUdzTIITRrQfHr4CgCA&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1024&bih=672#biv=i%7C5%3Bd%7CLQ1-K7fzTVmojM%3A

Comment: This is an image which shows (approximately) how the van is.

Comment: you should sit in the driver's seat. If the driver is as bad as you imply, you being in the driver's seat instead would probably make it the safest seat

Comment: @Jim that was funny, but I am underage. And may I know the reason behind the downvotes?

Comment: search me, I didn't downvote you. I don't really think this is a bad question either.

Comment: Well, that wasn't to you, so pls don't take it personally. And, I think the reason given below it truly stupid. These things really do discourage you as a beginner. Whenever I refer this site to people, I say, "do be cautious. Things can get ugly" I don't think this is what we aim to achieve as a community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends strongly on specifics of the crash, and where the other occupants of the car are.

Let's assume you slam straight into a brick wall.

If you sit in the back, there is nothing to hold you back at the time of the crash. You will slam hard into the seat in front of you (if you happen to have been sitting normally), and you might bruise or break your pelvis, knees, ribs, neck, and you might need some reconstructive facial surgery.

More importantly, if someone happens to be sitting in front of you, and that person is buckled up, there is a fairly large chance that you will injure that person even more severely than yourself. So if that is the case, you're "safest" in the backseat (at the expense of the safety of the person in front of you).

If no-one is sitting behind you, the safest place would be the front seat, *with* the belt buckled. Sure, the belt might bruise or break your pelvis, shoulder and/or collar bone (often cites as a reason *against* using belts), but that sure sounds a lot better than flying through the windshield and hitting the brick wall, head-first, full force.
Also, modern 3-point seat belts are designed to position the body so that the airbag can reach its maximum effectiveness.

Now assume the driver manages to break a little and throw the steering wheel to the side to try and avoid the oncoming danger. In that case there is that sudden steer, the probable roll-over of the vehicle that this action causes, and the crash.

People in the back are thrown to the side (steer), then get thrown to all sides of the car (roll-over), and finally hard in an arbitrary direction (crash). It's like putting eggs in a can and shake as hard as you can, and then slam the can to the ground. Needless to say, that won't be pleasant for the eggs. In any case, you will again be a living projectile being fired (perhaps multiple times) at the other passengers. Same goes for people in front without their seat-belts on.

If you sit buckled-up in the front, the initial aversion won't do as much harm (perhaps bruise your buttocks and overstretch some muscles), the rollover too is fairly well dampened (only your upper body will be thrown about; the belt will keep you seated though; provided you have a strong enough rooftop, this isn't so bad), and the crash can be anything from frontal (same as before), sideways (bad if you're on that side) to backwards (best case scenario).

Overall, you're best off when seated in front, *with* seat belts on.

But the safest place in a car? 
A webcam and speaker, connected to your laptop while you ride the train :)

Comment: That was a wonderful answer to read! Thanks a ton!! So, the journey is now over, and there was no accident at all. But, just FYI, I was the only guy except for the driver in the car, and I was thinking the same, ie sitting buckled up in front is the best, but my dad strongly disagreed with me, and implied that I am being foolish, so I asked this question..

Comment: That webcam and speaker example reminded me of Sheldon from The Big Bang Theory, from when he built a cyber-prescence of himself!

Answer (score 3):

According to the [National Highway Traffic Safety Administration](http://www.nhtsa.gov/) the safest place to sit is in the [centre of the back seat](http://www.nhtsa.gov/DOT/NHTSA/Communication%20&%20Consumer%20Information/Articles/Associated%20Files/LATCH_Report_12-2006.pdf).

I couldn't find anywhere they detail what research they used to come to this conclusion, but it seems reasonable on the grounds that it is the point in the car farthest away from anything that might intrude into the car body. You should note that their document assumes you are using a suitable safety belt (or since their article is about children a suitable booster seat).

Answer (score -2):

If the all the seats have seatbelts, the back of the car is safest, because you will not have as much forward acceleration as someone in the front seat when the car suddenly stops, because the distance between you and the front seat is less than that between the front seat and windshield. However, if someone hits your car in the back, this reasoning is irrelevant, because you could experience whiplash regardless of where you sit.